# How to enable an optional version of configure with autotools?

Tags: autotools

I want to create a version that will cause configure to build a specific version of a project.

Basically I want to create a configure that takes a commandline option 
./configure --enable-FOO 
Which builds with compiler flag -DFOO and some different compiler options.

How can I do this?

Comment: This is a pretty good overview of how to do that: https://autotools.io/autoconf/arguments.html

Answer (score 2):

You are asking two different questions here: first, how to add a `--enable` argument to `configure`; and second, how to have this argument affect the build in a specific way.

Adding an argument is done using `AC_ARG_ENABLE`.  It takes the name of the feature, a help string, and some optional actions.  So, for example:

```
AC_ARG_ENABLE(something, [enable the something feature])
```

(In real life you should use `AS_HELP_STRING` to construct the help string here.)

This adds `--enable-something` and `--disable-something` to `configure`; and, importantly, adds a new `enable_something` variable that can be used to check what the user did.

Defining a macro that is passed to the C compiler is done with `AC_DEFINE`.  So you can accomplish what you want by checking the new variable:

```
if test "$enable_something" = yes; then
  AC_DEFINE([SOMETHING], [1], [define to enable the something feature])
fi
```

This will cause `-DSOMETHING=1` to be passed to the compilation; or alternatively will emit `#define SOMETHING 1` into your `config.h`.